# c++ vector&array use same txt file

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, fstream

There is a text file. I need to take out the first number and put other numbers into an array. The size of the file is unknown. In my code, I first try to use `vector.size` to figure out its size and then build the array. Hope somebody can help me to see what's wrong.

Example input file:

```
3                   
2 2                   
output        
Can take out a=3;          
array[0]=2;array[1]=2;
```

Code:

```
int main()
{
    int n, inInt;
    vector <int> list;
    ifstream ifs("1.txt");

    int a;
    ifs>>a;
    std::vector<int> result;
    int temp;

    while(! ifs.eof())
    {
        ifs >> temp;
        result.push_back(temp);
    }

    int b;
    b=result.size();
    int numlist[b];

    for (int i=0;i<b;i++)
    {
        ifs>>numlist[i];
    } 
    cout<<numlist[0];

    ifs.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: u cannot use "int numlist[b];" what u need is a dynamic array. something like this: int *numlist = new int[b];

Comment: you mean I can do it totally without array?

Comment: This is still an array. But since you don't know its size before running your compiled code, this is a twist to create it dynamically

Comment: Sorry typo you mean I can do it totally without vector?

Comment: moreover, in your loop ifs is one value. which is the last '2' in your file

Comment: that is just for testing.The thing I want to do is after building the array can do a for loop

Comment: as I really did not study dynamic array.Is it possible to do in my stupid way(I admit it is really stupid)?

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n, inInt;
    vector <int> list;
    ifstream ifs("1.txt");
    int a;
    ifs>>a;
    std::vector<int> result;
    int temp;
    while(! ifs.eof())
    {
        ifs >> temp;
        if(ifs.good())     //Check to see did the operation work
        result.push_back(temp);
    }
    int b;
    b=result.size();
    cout<<result[0];

    ifs.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Then How can I get the nth element from the array?

Comment: It does not work.When I test it,it gives me a super huge incorrect number.

Comment: It does not work.When I test it,it gives me a super huge incorrect number.And when I tried several times,I will get different answers.

Comment: You're right. I just took your code and tweaked a few components of it without paying enough attention. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want a create an array of size you don't know you must use:

```
int *numlist = new int[b];
```

and in the end of your code:

```
delete[] numlist;
```

Secondly, what's the point in reading the file again when you have a vector which holds values from the file? Wouldn't it be easier to just do:

```
for (i=0; i < b; i++)
     numlist[i] = result[i];
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: @user2593970 just a tip for stackoverflow.com, accept of of the two answers so people stay encouraged to answer you. Just click the tick button to the left of the answer (you can accept only one answer per question, make it the best one)